# Aspect oriented programming in r: Any libraries available?

Tags: r, aop

Are there any R-project packages that implement AOP?  Or even better an example of an R package that uses any such AOP library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I researched this topic about six months ago. Here's what i found (which i checked/updated upon viewing your question):

There is [one package](http://code.google.com/p/r-connect/) i'm aware of directed specifically/exclusively to AOP (and which predictably is related to event monitoring/logging)--called '**r-connect**.' Not available in CRAN as far as i know. At the moment i haven't used it enough to give you any useful feedback. For svn checkout:

"svn checkout http://r-connect.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ r-connect-read-only"

Answer (score -1):

The r-connect package has been abandoned.